# Visual Studioにてコードレビュー機能が利用できない

Tags: visual-studio, azure

オンプレ版のAzure DevOps Server 2019上で構成されているコレクションのプロジェクトに対して、Visual Studio 2015で接続しています。

以下のリンクにある手順を踏みコードレビューが要求しようと思いましたが、以下のメッセージ表示され要求できません。
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/get-code-reviewed-vs?view=azure-devops

> この機能は、Team Foundation 管理者がこのチーム プロジェクト用に有効化するまでは使用できません。

Reposでは、GitではなくTFVCを使用しています。
表示されるメッセージの文面からして、TFSからDevOpsにアップグレードした際に”何らか”の設定からコードレビュー機能の有効化がされていないと読み取ったのですが、それを設定する方法が分かりません。

Answer (score 1):

TFSからDevOpsへアップグレードしていたため、下記リンクにある通り手動で機能追加を行う必要があります。
[Add updates to projects manually / プロジェクトに更新を手動追加する](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/devops/reference/upgrade/add-features-manually)